# Can I download only .NET Command Prompt?

Tags: c#

I am Learning C#. I use SharpDevelop IDE to develop applications. I don't want to install Visual C# because I have limited free space on my hard drive. But now I require Command Prompt .NET to develop dll-files and compile C# files. Can I download only Command Prompt? If so, where can I download it?

Comment: Hi, When you install .Net you get the C# compiler which is a command line tool. Like the answer below mentions it is called csc.

Comment: Hard drives are cheap these days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're probably looking for is not a "command prompt" but the C# compiler (`csc`). It is included in the [.Net framework](http://www.microsoft.com/net/download) which you probably have installed already (if not: you'll need it to run .Net applications anyway). [This documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/78f4aasd.aspx) describes how to use CSC from a "normal command prompt" as well as the "Visual Studio Command Prompt".